# Problem with syntax error at or near 'select'

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis, qgis, pgrouting

I'm trying to code about how to create isochrones, this is my code:

```
SELECT i As time_access,
ST_SetSRID(pgr_pointsAsPolygon(
‘SELECT id, ST_X (geom) AS x, ST_Y (geom) As y
FROM dd_caserne
WHERE access_time <= ‘|| i :: text), 4326) As geom
FROM generate_series(60,300,60)
As i
ORDER BY i DESC;
```

And the error I am getting is as follows:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "id"
LINE 4: ‘SELECT id, ST_X (geom) AS x, ST_Y (geom) As y
```

can someone help me ?

Comment: get rid of those spaces: ``SELECT id, ST_X(geom) AS x, ST_Y(geom) AS y``

Comment: Are you using the wrong type of single quotes? You have `‘` but want `'`.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO.

You're using a wrong character to quote the `SELECT` string. Use single quotes `'` instead of `´`:

```
SELECT 
  i AS time_access,
  ST_SetSRID(pgr_pointsAsPolygon(
    'SELECT id, ST_X(geom) AS x, ST_Y(geom) AS y
     FROM dd_caserne WHERE access_time <= '|| i::text), 4326) AS geom
FROM generate_series(60,300,60) AS i
ORDER BY i DESC;
```

See also [`dollar-quoted strings`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59679089/2275388)

**Note**: if you're using pgRouting 3.0+ please check [`pgr_alphaShape`](https://docs.pgrouting.org/3.0/en/pgr_alphaShape.html#pgr-alphashape)

Comment: Hi Jim, when i use this form it gives me this error : ERROR:  function pgr_pointsaspolygon(text) does not exist

Comment: @lirimbokshi it is now a totally different issue. If you do have pgrounting installed, can you check if it still has this function? Or maybe use: https://docs.pgrouting.org/3.0/en/pgr_alphaShape.html#pgr-alphashape